# Is it now impossible to send notifications to User via Facebook API?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I can't understand. There is no way to send notifications to User via Facebook API?

```
 FB.api('/id/notifications?access_token=' + fb_token +
'&template=Closer&href=...', function(response) {   
alert(JSON.stringify(response));

    });
```

This request returns that `manage_notifications` permission is required which deprecated(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-manage_notifications), and I can't anything else on Facebook docs which would allow doing this.  Is it now impossible at all?

And there is no way to invite friends in this way if it's not Facebook game, but just a website using it's API and having permission(if it's still possible)?

Comment: How to invite people to your app is explained in their FAQ https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_104376946653191

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/appnotifications

Comment: @luschn that is exactly what I have implemented. This request returns that manage_notifications permission is required which is deprecated

Comment: @WizKid for web app there is only message way, and I need notifications

Comment: What you need doesn't matter. The link that I gave you list all ways you can do it. If you don't want to do it in that way that doesn't matter.

Comment: you can only use notifications for users who are already using your app, btw.

Comment: @luschn ye, already using. it's just not possible anymore

Comment: "just a website using it's API" - you can´t use notifications for that anyway. notifications are for canvas apps only.